# Centering svg image used on clustered bar chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have appended an SVG image to my clustered bar chart but need the image to sit in the centre of the two values. Currently it's sitting underneath the first value only.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/ua3L7sv8/2/)
Any ideas how this can be done?  I know I could probably fudge but using +30 for example in the x attribute but ideally there's just a way I can force it to sit centrally.

```
svg.selectAll(".images")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x0(d.xx)) + ",0)"; })

      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.dataNew; })
        .enter()
      .append("svg:image")

       .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.xx )  } )
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom-40)
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", 40)
       .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return "http://pngimg.com/uploads/football/football_PNG52789football_PNG52789.png"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math you need is:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (x0(d.xx) + (x0.rangeBand() - x1.rangeBand()) / 2) + ",0)";
})
```

Here is your JSFiddle with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/4bsvr6y2/